Horror movie with hunter, the pack of dogs and island
There is a group of young prisoners arrives on the island for correctional labor. 
In the past there was a camp of soldiers over there. When they arrive they meet the pack of big dogs and a hunter who orders dogs what to do. One by one they are dying in attempt to leave the island. 
It was released in 2005-2013. It was in color.
The language was English.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

@Paulie_D, I edited. Now can you upvote?

Could it be a combination of movies you are thinking of? It sounds like 'the condemned', which came out in 2007, and also The Hunger Games, which had dog like creatures attacking the protagonists.

Could it be Wilderness (2006, UK)?
Plot:

Juvenile delinquents gets sent to a small British island after a
  fellow prisoners death, where they have to fight for survival

Synopsis:

A group of juvenile delinquents are forced to fight for their lives
  after being sent the forest for an exercise in teamwork and tracked by
a crossbow-wielding madman with a pack of flesh-eating dogs. The Young
  Offenders Institution is the kind of place kids are sent when all hope
  is lost. In order to test their mettle in an environment where every
  decision counts, the powers that be at the Young Offenders Institution
  send their worst offenders into deep into the woods for a tough-love
  lesson in character-building. Suddenly surrounded by dense
  forestation, deadly rapids, and a jagged coastline that makes escape
  virtually impossible...


Yes. It is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for the attention.

@theguest: No problem, I'll keep that in mind.
